# Adding Point Objects To ZedGraph

Tags: c#, point, zedgraph

A nice extension exists for ZedGraph to plot markers/points ([PointObj.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/zedgraph/feature-requests/79/)). However, I am having trouble rendering the point on the graph.

When I call the ZedGraph.Invalidate() function, the marker is drawn momentarily but then disappears.

In the following code, the variable zedGraph is the visible graph object on the form UI.

```
 // Create point
 ZedGraph.PointObj point = new ZedGraph.PointObj(5, 10000, 50, 50, ZedGraph.SymbolType.Square, Color.Green);
 ZedGraph.PaneBase paneBase = zedGraph.GraphPane;
 point.Fill = new ZedGraph.Fill(Color.Green);
 System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = zedGraph.CreateGraphics();

 // Draw point to graph
 point.Draw(graphics, paneBase, paneBase.CalcScaleFactor());

 // Re-draw graph, but point only flashes momentarily. 
 zedGraph.Invalidate();
```

EDIT: I realise there are other ways of adding "points", such as described here ([Labelling and circle a specific point in zedgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986372/labelling-and-circle-a-specific-point-in-zedgraph)). But it would be still good to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know much about the `PointObj` class, but why do you need to call `zedGraph.Invalidate`?  Does `point.Draw` not display the point on its own?

Comment: It is my belief that point.Draw adds the point object to the graph object, and then .Invalidate is used to redraw the graph with all the current included objects.

Comment: Got a picture?  Why do you use pointsObj if the same functionality exists in vanilla Zedgraph?

Comment: No picture sorry, this question was asked ages ago :-) But, this is vanilla Zedgraph (PointObj is part of ZedGraph).And the other way seems more like a hack, this seems like the proper way of adding a point.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the point to the GraphObjList after creation

zedGraph.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(point);