# Plot Point in ZedGraph C#?

Tags: c#, point, shapes, zedgraph

Well this is my question, I have a ZedGraph, now I want to put some points in the ZedGraph, I have my simple class Point wich it have, the X & Y values, fist I check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226156/adding-point-objects-to-zedgraph), but not  answered, at the moment don't work, anyone know how to put just a simple point, my goal is drawing shapes like this one [Secciones](http://sourceforge.net/projects/secciones/) but I dont know how make this

Answer (score 1):

I believe ZedGraph is the wrong tool for what you want to achieve. You should be using  [**GDI+ drawing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z5dw491.aspx) do draw your points, lines, rectangles and other shapes. It forms part of C#.NET.